Connect managed instance from .net console 4.8 app
I am trying to create a .NET 4.8 console app (VS 2022) and establish a connect with managed instance in Azure.
I have followed the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/public-endpoint-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal

Enabled public endpoint
Added inbound rule
Created sample app with the following code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace MyConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var connectionString = @"Server=tcp:mymi.public.XXXX.database.windows.net,3342;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication='Active Directory Integrated';";

            var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionString);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection state is not open");
            }
        }
    }
}

I am getting the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

I have also tried installing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient nuget package but end up with same error. My SQL Managed Instance has Azure AD auth enabled and set to a group which I am a part of.

Are you getting the error locally?

Yes I am getting it from my dev box @Harshitha

Are you able to login to the instance from local ssms ?

I am able to connect using Azure data studio

Once try with ssms

Can I try to connect with it from my dev box directly? Can you please tell me what options should I choose as I do not have sql auth configured for the managed instance? It is MS Entra and a group is the admin

I removed ad auth and reset the password but I am still getting the error: Connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond after a period of time. I tried with server name as host from Overview and from Networking public endpoint which has port number as well. My NSG has 2 rules apart from my 3342 public inbound. 1: Any port, any protocol, Source: Loadbalancer, destination: db subnet 2. Same as previous except source and dest are both db subnet.

Have you configured NSG ?

Yes I have shared the rule in comment, I also tried one more thing I did SQL auth from a vm that is part of the vnet and it connected with the ado.net connection string public endpoint
